# Función lambda no reconoce a objeto de clase tk.Button

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy tratando de hacer una calculadora con GUI y en este momento estoy tratando de hacer que cuando se presione un botón este cambié su `relief`, estoy tratando de usarlo pero el intérprete me arroja este error.

```
 a = tk.Button(self, text="1", command=lambda: a.config(relief=GROOVE), relief=FLAT,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'
```

No sé si adjuntar el botón a una variable es la mejor forma de hacerlo:

```
a = tk.Button(self, text="1", command=lambda: a.config(relief=GROOVE), relief=FLAT,
                      font=myfont, bg="ghost white").grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="NSEW", padx=3, pady=3, ipadx=0,
                                                          ipady=0)
```

Traté de hacerlo así también:

```
tk.Button(self, text="1", command=lambda: self.config(relief=GROOVE), relief=FLAT,
                      font=myfont, bg="ghost white").grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="NSEW", padx=3, pady=3, ipadx=0,
                                                          ipady=0)
```

Pero al parecer lo que hace es modificar el objeto `self` (el cual es el frame en el que están los botones)

Espero que me puedan ayudar

(Aquí está todo el código)

```
from Calculator import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def operation_to_do(symbol):
    op = ""

    if symbol == "+":
        op = "Plus"
    elif symbol == "-":
        op = "Subtract"
    elif symbol == "X":
        op = "Multiplication"
    elif symbol == "/":
        op = "Divide"
    elif symbol == "C":
        pass
    elif symbol == "CE":
        pass

    return op


def call_function_button(self, variable, entry):
    self.configure(text="Hello")

    insert_number(variable, entry)


def insert_number(variable, entry):
    result = variable + entry
    return result


def operation():
    pass


def transform_conjunt(conjunt):
    value = int(conjunt)
    return value


conjunt = ""
conjunt2 = ""


class MainFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.grid()
        self.config(bg="white")

        def change_button():
            pass

        myfont = Font(family="Arial", size=15)

        self.i = Image.open("C:/Users/Darwin Lozada/Desktop/1.png")
        self.i2 = self.i.resize((100, 100))
        self.image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.i2)

        tk.Label(self, text="TEST", font=myfont).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="NSEW", columnspan=3, padx=2.5, pady=2.5)

        # Numbers Buttons

        tk.Button(self, text="1", command=lambda: self.config(relief=GROOVE), relief=FLAT,
                  font=myfont, bg="ghost white").grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="NSEW", padx=3, pady=3, ipadx=0,
                                                      ipady=0)

        tk.Button(self, text="2", font=myfont,
                  relief=FLAT, activebackground="gainsboro", bg="ghost white").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="NSEW",
                                                                                    padx=3,
                                                                                    pady=3)
        tk.Button(self, text="3", command=lambda: call_function_button(self, conjunt, "3"), font=myfont,
                  relief=FLAT, bg="ghost white").grid(column=2, row=1, sticky="NSEW", padx=3, pady=3)
        tk.Button(self, text="4", command=lambda: call_function_button(self, conjunt, "4"), font=myfont,
                  relief=FLAT, bg="ghost white").grid(
            column=0, row=2, sticky="NSEW", padx=3, pady=3)
        tk.Button(self, text="5", command=lambda: call_function_button(self, conjunt, "5"), font=myfont,
                  relief=FLAT, bg="ghost white").grid(
            column=1, row=2, sticky="NSEW", padx=3, pady=3)
        tk.Button(self, text="6", command=lambda: call_function_button(self, conjunt, "6"), font=myfont,
                  relief=FLAT, bg="ghost white").grid(
            column=2, row=2, sticky="NSEW", padx=3, pady=3)
        tk.Button(self, text="7", command=lambda: call_function_button(self, conjunt, "7"), font=myfont,
                  relief=FLAT, bg="ghost white").grid(
            column=0, row=3, sticky="NSEW", padx=3, pady=3)
        tk.Button(self, text="8", command=lambda: call_function_button(self, conjunt, "8"), font=myfont,
                  relief=FLAT, bg="ghost white").grid(
            column=1, row=3, sticky="NSEW", padx=3, pady=3)
        tk.Button(self, text="9", command=lambda: call_function_button(self, conjunt, "9"), font=myfont,
                  relief=FLAT, bg="ghost white").grid(
            column=2, row=3, sticky="NSEW", padx=3, pady=3)
        tk.Button(self, text="0", command=lambda: call_function_button(self, conjunt, "0"), font=myfont,
                  relief=FLAT, bg="ghost white").grid(
            column=1, row=4, sticky="NSEW", padx=3, pady=3)

        # Operations Buttons

        tk.Button(self, text="+", font=myfont, command=lambda: operation_to_do("+"), relief=FLAT).grid(
            column=3, row=0, sticky="NSEW", padx=3, pady=3)
        tk.Button(self, text="-", font=myfont, command=lambda: operation_to_do("-"), relief=FLAT).grid(
            column=3, row=1, sticky="NSEW", padx=3, pady=3)
        tk.Button(self, text="X", font=myfont, command=lambda: operation_to_do("X"), relief=FLAT).grid(
            column=3, row=2, sticky="NSEW", padx=3, pady=3)
        tk.Button(self, text="/", font=myfont, command=lambda: operation_to_do("/"), relief=FLAT).grid(
            column=3, row=3, sticky="NSEW", padx=3, pady=3)
        tk.Button(self, text="C", font=myfont, command=lambda: operation_to_do("C"), relief=FLAT).grid(
            column=0, row=4, sticky="NSEW", padx=3, pady=3)
        tk.Button(self, text="CE", font=myfont, command=lambda: operation_to_do("CE"), relief=FLAT).grid(
            column=2, row=4, sticky="NSEW", padx=3, pady=3)

        # Result Button

        tk.Button(self, text="=", font=myfont, relief=FLAT).grid(column=3, row=4, sticky="NSEW", padx=3, pady=3)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)

        def give_result(self):
            pass


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Calculadora")
    root.minsize(300, 350)

    buttons_frame = MainFrame(root)
    buttons_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSEW")
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Intuyo por dónde va el problema, pero no hay forma de estar seguro si no pones un código más completo, un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). ¿Has probado a cambiar la función lambda por una función normal o un método?

Comment: Sip lo he intentado. La función ```call_function_button``` la hice con esa intención pero tampoco sirvió

Answer (score 1):

```
 a = tk.Button(self, text="1", command=lambda: a.config(relief=GROOVE), relief=FLAT)
```

El botón necesita como primer argumento una ventana,simplemente seria remplazar el `self` por tu `ventana` quedaría algo así:

```
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import GROOVE
from tkinter import FLAT
from tkinter import Button

ventana = Tk()

class botonCualquiera():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Boton = Button(ventana, text="1", relief=FLAT)
        self.Boton.bind('<Button-1>', self.cuandoPresionen)
        self.Boton.place(x=50,y=50)

    def cuandoPresionen(self,event):
        self.Boton.config(relief=GROOVE)


botonCualquiera()

ventana.mainloop()
```

Luego si lo que quieres es que cada vez que se presione sobre el botón cambie su configuración (En este caso el relief) tienes que hace uso de `bind`que le asigne una función (`cuandoPresionen`) al botón cada vez que hagan click sobre él.

Si quieres también puedes usar lambda, para reducir el tamaño del código, solo abría que poner el lambda en el bind, quedaría algo asi:

```
self.Boton.bind('<Button-1>', lambda _: self.Boton.config(relief=GROOVE))
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.

---

### Edit:

Primero asignas una variable al Botón `b1`, luego lo colocas como quieras, en este caso `grid` y por ultimo `bindeas` al botón

```
b1 = Button(self, text="1",relief=FLAT,font=myfont, bg="ghost white")
b1.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="NSEW", padx=3, pady=3, ipadx=0,ipady=0)
b1.bind('<Button-1>', lambda _: b1.config(bd=10))
```

Y así con todos los botones, en este caso use bd (border width) para que se note la diferencia entre el botón 1 y los demás, cualquier otra duda me avisas :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Pero tengo una duda. Cómo hago para implementar el método ```bind``` cuando estoy definiendo el widget Button. Voy a actualizar la pregunta con el código para que veas mejor a lo que me refiero

Comment: Te referís al error que da call_function_button() ?

Comment: No. Esa función está ahí como un intento fallido de modificar el widget jajaja. Lo que me refiero es que en qué parte del código debo escribir el ```bind```

Comment: Declaré el widget en una variable llamada ```button1```. y luego usé el método ```bind``` Pero ahora arroja ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'```

Comment: Ahora edito el post original.

Comment: Sale el mismo error : ``` AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'``` Qué problema jajaja. Hice lo mismo que tu pero no entiendo porque no detecta el b1 como un tk.Button

Comment: que raro xD, a mi me funciona bien, pasame exactamente las 3 lineas del boton

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105178/discussion-between-franco-and-thebigbosslong).